# Get sentences containing a keyword from paragraph

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to extract sentences that contain the word `island` or `Island` from a paragraph. Each sentence begins with a capital letter and ends with a period.

**Paragraph as string**

`"
The islands were settled from the second century AD by a series of local empires. In 1819, Sir Stamford Raffles founded modern Singapore as a trading post of the East India Company; after the company collapsed, the islands were ceded to Britain and became part of its Straits Settlements in 1826. During World War II, Singapore was occupied by Japan. It gained independence from Britain in 1963, by uniting with other former British territories to form Malaysia, but was expelled two years later over ideological differences. After early years of turbulence, and despite lacking natural resources and a hinterland, the nation developed rapidly as an Asian Tiger economy, based on external trade and its human capital.
"` (Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore)

**Ideal result as elements in an array:**

- The islands were settled from the second century AD by a series of local empires.
- In 1819, Sir Stamford Raffles founded modern Singapore as a trading post of the East India Company; after the company collapsed, the islands were ceded to Britain and became part of its Straits Settlements in 1826.

I found examples on how to do this in other languages, like Java ([Regex to find sentence containing specific word (java) from paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990083)). However, the same Regex didn't work for Ruby.

Is this possible to do using Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using two regular expressions, one to break the string into sentences, the other to extract sentences containing the word "island" or "islands", with the first letter possibly capitalized.

```
str.split(/(?<=\.)\s+/).select { |s| s =~ /\b[iI]slands?\b/ }
  #=> ["The islands were settled from the second century AD by a series of local empires.",
  #    "In 1819, Sir Stamford Raffles founded modern Singapore as a trading post of
  #     the East India Company; after the company collapsed, the islands were ceded to
  #     Britain and became part of its Straits Settlements in 1826. *
```

- `/(?<=\.)\s+/` matches a period in a positive lookbehind followed by one or more spaces.
- `/\b[iI]slands?\b/` matches the strings "island", "Island", "islands" and "Islands", surrounded by word breaks (to avoid matching, for example, "islander").

<sup>* I've added two line breaks here to make it more readable.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably go without regexp. They are hard to read and understand when you come back to the code later. A simple splitting into sentences and then selecting based on keyword should do:

```
input.split('.').select do |sentence|
  sentence.downcase.include?('island')
end
```

Of course there might be other '.' in the paragraph that are not used to separate sentences.

Comment: This will remove the period after the sentences.

Comment: true:-) Should be easy to add them back again though.

Comment: What if a sentence contains the word "islander"? I'd probably go without Ruby. Ruby is hard to read and understand when you come back to the code later. No? Not if you've gained a certain competence with the language, which is true for any language, including regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Following what you said, the most straightforward is perhaps:

```
string.scan(/(?=[A-Z])[^.]*island[^.]*\./i)
# => [
#   "The islands were settled from the second century AD by a series of local empires.",
#   "In 1819, Sir Stamford Raffles founded modern Singapore as a trading post of the East India Company; after the company collapsed, the islands were ceded to Britain and became part of its Straits Settlements in 1826."
# ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution produces the correct result for the example text.

```
text = " The islands were settled from the second century AD by a series of local empires. In 1819, Sir Stamford Raffles founded modern Singapore as a trading post of the East India Company; after the company collapsed, the islands were ceded to Britain and became part of its Straits Settlements in 1826. During World War II, Singapore was occupied by Japan. It gained independence from Britain in 1963, by uniting with other former British territories to form Malaysia, but was expelled two years later over ideological differences. After early years of turbulence, and despite lacking natural resources and a hinterland, the nation developed rapidly as an Asian Tiger economy, based on external trade and its human capital."

matches = text.scan(/\b[A-Z][^.]+[Ii]sland[^.]+?\./)

matches.each do |match|
  puts "Found: #{match}"
end
```

This produces the following output:

```
Found: The islands were settled from the second century AD by a series of local empires.
Found: In 1819, Sir Stamford Raffles founded modern Singapore as a trading post of the East India Company; after the company collapsed, the islands were ceded to Britain and became part of its Straits Settlements in 1826.
```

Based on the link provided, additional support for other sentence terminator (e.g. "!" and "?") could be added simply with this slight change:

```
matches = text.scan(/\b[A-Z][^.!?]+[Ii]sland[^.!?]+?[.!?]/)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex

```
(?<=^|[.?!])(.*?[Ii]sland.*?(?:[.?!]|$))
```

**[Rubular Demo](http://rubular.com/r/BcrTYvYoqM)**

*Ruby Code*

```
print str.scan(/(?<=^|[.?!])(.*?[Ii]sland.*?(?:[.?!]|$))/)
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/nZT9ZK)**